# ActionBarDrawerToggle does not open drawer until first slide

Tags: android, drawerlayout

I am using Google Design Support Library and DrawerLayout.

Setup:

```
final DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
NavigationView drawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
if(mDrawerToggle == null) {
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, mToolbar, R.string.open, R.string.feather_close);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

When I start my app, the ripple effect of the hamburger icon is shown but the drawer is not opened. When I open the drawer at least one time by sliding from the left, the hamburger icon works for the entire runtime.
I don't have a special listener on the toggle button or the drawer itself and the onOptionsItemSelected method is not called.

Please help me to find out what happens.

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found it: I accidentally had `android:visibility="gone"` in my NavigationView.
What a freaky side effect.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it using it :

```
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Comment: That is exactly what I do...
+ setDrawerListener is deprecated

Comment: What version of DrawerLayout you are using? i'm using v4. 
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;